# Select entities using an array of values that represents the another field (`in`)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

First, sorry for the cryptic title, but I really don't know how to write one more clear.

**This is not a question about `join` but is a question about using `in` in conjunction with `join`.**

I'm going to explain my situation.

I have an `array` that contains a list of slugged names of cities:

```
$cities = ['new_york', 'rome', 'hong_kong'];
```

These cities are in a table `cities` and have each one their own ID:

```
------------------
| ID | slug      |
|  1 | new_york  |
|  2 | rome      |
|  3 | hong_kong |
------------------
```

Then I have another table `listings` that contain the listing of various venues.
Each `Listing` has a field `city` that relates the `Listing` with the `City` in which it is.
The relation is a `ManyToOne`:

```php
# Listing

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ListingRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="listings", schema="app")
 */
class Listing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false) */
    private string $name;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=City::class, inversedBy="listings") */
    private City $city;

    ...
}
```

and then

```php
# City

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CityRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="cities", schema="app")
 */
class City
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false) */
    private string $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false) */
    private string $slug;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Listing::class, mappedBy="city") */
    private Collection $listings;

    ...
}
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

Passing an array of slugs of the `City`(ies), I'd like to select all the `Listing`s that belong to each passed `City`.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

One possible solution is to

1. First select all cities by their slugs in the array,
2. Get the list of entities `City` and cycle them to get their IDs
3. Pass the list of IDs to the `ListingRepository` and use `in`

Something like this:

```php
# Not tested, but it should work (may require some bug fixing)

...
    /**
     * @param City[] $cities
     *
     * @return Listing[]
     */
    public function findAllByCities(array $cities):array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
        $citiesIds = $this->getCitiesIds($cities);

        return $qb
            ->select('l')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('l.city', ':cities'))
            ->setParameter('cities', $citiesIds, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @param City[] $cities
     *
     * @return int[]
     */
    private function getCitiesIds(array $cities):array
    {
        return array_map(static fn(City $city): int => $city->getId(), $cities);
    }
...
```

The drawback of this approach are that:

1. I have to perform a query to get the list of cities
2. I have to cycle each returned city to get its ID

This may become heavy if the cities in the list are numerous.

**QUESTION**

Is there a wy to select all the `Listing`s in each passed `City` but using the slugs instead of first retrieving their ID?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can join the associated table.

```
public function findAllByCities(array $cities):array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');

    return $qb
        ->select('l')
        ->join('l.city', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.slug', ':cities'))
        ->setParameter('cities', $cities, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```